# Why shouldn't I send .Net Framework Objects to Web Service as Byte Arrays?

Tags: .net, web-services, serialization

I've always wanted to send objects that you can serialize in XML across websites, such as a dictionary or an exception (because I'm perverse).

I know for example in the dictionary, I shouldn't send custom objects (as the value part) in case I upgrade the class library on the web service, but not on the client as this would lead to a mismatch in the byte array and it wouldn't be able to be de-serialised at the other end correctly.

But I don't see a problem with an exception, or an image object etc?

Are there any other reasons, such as performance concerns that I should be aware of?

Is this a valid approach to web services if I use it carefully? This is more of a theoretical question, so any elaboration on answers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea where you got this idea, but pretend you didn't.

You should simply not be sending platform-specific types across a web service boundary. This can cause problems even between .NET Framework versions.

Instead, you should abstract the value that you are sending - decide what information in the `Exception` is important, and just send that.

Comment: Also, if you don't capture an exception in your webservice then it is wrapped up in a soap exception, which actually could be a sercurity risk as it may expose more of your code base workings, etc. than you wish to do in a web service.

Comment: what I do currently is send an adapter object that exposes the data I want to send, so don't worry about where the idea came from - I know it is a bad Idea, I'm just wanted to know as many reasons as possible, why it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Web Services are often used as a technology-agnostic integration mechanism - the other end need not be a Windows machine at all. In the homogeneous case, Windows at both ends, there are more natural remoting technologies.

So I would try to stick to inter-operable payloads. There are various approaches for dealing with attachments for things such as pictures.

Comment: Thanks @djna, do you have an example of the various approaches for dealing with attachments for things such as pictures, I've never needed to do this? I've used MTOM before, but only for files, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, MTOM. SOAP with Attachments was another, but not all vendors supported that, particularly Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There I nothing wrong with binary data as long as it is interoperable. BinaryFormatter would be silly, but there are others. For example google designed "protobuf" / "protocol buffers" for **exactly** this purpose. There are protobuf implementations in many many platforms including several in .NET.

Most of google's apps, from what I gather, work this way. The only downside (the same as with XML) is that it isn't very convenient from JavaScript. But from a web service is is ideal; both CPU and bandwidth efficient, and version-tolerant.